# Microsoft Graph API in German environment - InvalidAuthenticationToken (Message: Access token validation failure)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

we use Microsoft.Graph dll (v. 1.20.0). When using in Global environment everything works fine. Now I have tried to make same calls in German environment but every call ends with exception: [Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken, Message: Access token validation failure]. I have tried these endpoints: Me, Domains, Subscriptions.

On my side only device auth url and graphApi url has changed . I authorize via device authentication on https://login.microsoftonline.de/. Then bearer token is get from https://graph.microsoft.de. The user I authorized with is administrator for subscriptionId (see code below)

Code is something like this:

```
var http = new Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider();
var credentials = new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, accessToken);
Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProvider provider = new AuthenticationProvider(credentials);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(provider, http);
var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); // ERROR
```

It looks to me that error is not related to invalid token. I have read that some API endpoints are not yet supported in German cloud. Maybe this is the cause...

Any ideas what to try?

Thank you.

Decoded (and blinded) token:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "4GrWG3nKdEoekxxxxxxxxxxxpyXQ5yky7_HTAg",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "J1XZUkznV-JEe-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "kid": "J1XZUkznV-JEe-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}.{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.de",
  "iss": "https://sts.microsoftonline.de/146e589e-f5c2-4dd2-95dd-a94c3ffa00f8/",
  "iat": 1575010843,
  "nbf": 1575010843,
  "exp": 1575014743,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "ASQA2/8FAAAApfed4j4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMd4v7aEsASSm8LxIElw=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Microsoft Azure CLI",
  "appid": "04b07795-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "ipaddr": "XX.XX.XX.XX",
  "name": "Chuck Norris",
  "oid": "bc7a9fcf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-557ce18e4fd6",
  "platf": "14",
  "puid": "10032XXXXXXXXXD1DB9",
  "scp": "AuditLog.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All Group.ReadWrite.All User.ReadWrite.All",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "hq-v5yL38qnRxxxxxxxxxxxxufB-I-17BNqy-Rp0",
  "tid": "146e589e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a94c3ffa00f8",
  "unique_name": "chuck@norris.onmicrosoft.de",
  "upn": "chuck@norris.onmicrosoft.de",
  "uti": "CgOXXXXXX2k-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1495192142
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: Can you decode the JWT using a site like jwt.ms and post it here so we can check the audience and other token claims? (Please don't post the actual token here). Also, regarding your comment that some API endpoints in German cloud aren't supported that is not the root cause here. /me should work!

Comment: Thank You, Alex, decoded token added to original message.

Answer (score 0):

answer to this was simple, my fault. Token is OK, from Germany cloud as it should be. Problem was in that GraphServiceClient was using default baseUrl (https://graph.microsoft.**COM**/v1.0) and it was not talking with German cloud https://graph.microsoft.**DE**/v1.0.